# Creation of virtual assistant with Openai artificial intelligence using Python and Kivy library

Tags: python, kivy, openai-api

as the title suggests, I created a virtual assistant with this code

```
import json
import openai

with open("secrets.json") as f:
    secrets = json.load(f)
    api_key = secrets["api_key"]

openai.api_key = api_key


def get_response(messages: list):
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=messages,
        temperature=1.0  # 0.0 - 2.0
    )
    return response.choices[0].message


if __name__ == "__main__":
    messages = [
        {"role": "system", "content": "Sei un assistente virtuale chiamata JOI e parli italiano."}
    ]
    try:
        while True:
            user_input = input("\nYou: ")
            messages.append({"role": "user", "content": user_input})
            new_message = get_response(messages=messages)
            print(f"\nJOI: {new_message['content']}")

            messages.append(new_message)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("see you soon bye!")
```

the virtual assistant works fine in the terminal but i would like the messages to be written to a label using kivy so i installed kivy and kivymd and wrote this code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV =    '''
Screen:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        ScrollView:
            MDLabel:
                id: mdlab
                text: "Virtual Assistant!"
                size_hint_y: None
                padding_x: 30
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                text_size: self.width, None

        MDRaisedButton:
            id: mdbu
            text: "GO!"
            size_hint_x: 1
            on_press: app.message()
            '''

class virtualAssistantApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.title = "Virtual Assistant"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"  # "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "400"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def message(self):
        self.root.ids["mdlab"].text = "Button pressed"

virtualAssistantApp().run()
```

how do i insert the message in the label with id mdlab?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `+=` instead of `=` in your `message()` method:

```
def message(self):
    self.root.ids["mdlab"].text += "\nButton pressed"
```